# how to convert a string to array of object in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, typescript

Hi all I have one string which I need to convert in array of object in node JS.
as :

```
var result = "[{'path': '/home/media/fileyear.jpg', 'vectors': [0.1234, 0.457, 0.234]}, 
{'path': '/home/media/fileyear2.jpg', 'vectors': [0.134, 0.557, 0.634]}]"
```

to

```
[{'path': '/home/media/fileyear.jpg', 'vectors': [0.1234, 0.457, 0.234]}, {'path': '/home/media/fileyear2.jpg', 'vectors': [0.134, 0.557, 0.634]}]
```

How can I do that using typescript or javascript in nodeJs.

Comment: If the keys were wrapped in `"` instead of `'` you could `JSON.parse` by the looks of it.

Comment: That first code segment is one big syntax error.  Are you *sure* that's what you're using?  Are you just asking how to correct that error?  Something else?

Comment: sorry by mistake i wrapped it with single quotes. It should be wrapped with double quotes. I am using JSON.parse to convert that string to array of object but getting one syntax error as SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) \n @Palladium02

Comment: I believe JSON requires the keys and strings to be wrapped in double quotes, rather than single quotes. How Is this string generated in the first place?

Comment: all properties must use double quotes. `"path": "/home/media/fileyear.jpg"`

Comment: its comming from python script which i am running as a child process in node js. @mykaf

Comment: Can you fix the sender to produce valid JSON?

Comment: As @jabaa says, the problem is the child process creating invalid JSON. That is what you should really focus on, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var jsonString = "[{'path': '/home/media/fileyear.jpg', 'vectors': [0.1234, 0.457, 0.234]}, {'path': '/home/media/fileyear2.jpg', 'vectors': [0.134, 0.557, 0.634]}]";
```

// Replacing single quotes with double quotes

`var correctedString = jsonString.replace(/'/g, '"');`

// Then Parse the corrected JSON string into an object

`var result = JSON.parse(correctedString);`

Comment: OP had single quotes wrapped around on his original question.

Comment: Glad to help Rajesh!